# Model building keyw not recognised

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to build a model to predict which ['award'] people will receive in my subset.

I'm getting a key error with 'award' but I'm not sure why.

Here is my code(error in line2):

```
subset = pd.get_dummies(subset) #one-hot encoding
labels = np.array(subset['award']) #Labels= value to predict
subset= subset.drop('award', axis = 1) #remove labesl from subset, axis 1=columns
subset_list = list(subset.columns) #save subset names for later use
subset = np.array(subset)# Convert to numpy array
```

[award] typically contains: Best Director, Best Actor  etc.

An example of a row in subset is:

```
          birthplace         DOB         race    award
Id        
670454353 Chisinau, Moldova  30/09/1895  White   Best Director
```

Before pd.get_dummies columns->

```
Index(['birthplace', 'date_of_birth', 'race_ethnicity', 'year_of_award',
   'award', 'ldob', 'year', 'award_age', 'country', 'bin'],
  dtype='object')
```

After pd.get_dummies(subset)->

```
Index(['year_of_award', 'ldob', 'year', 'award_age',
   'birthplace_Arlington, Va, US', 'birthplace_Astoria, Ny, US',
   'birthplace_Athens, Ga, US', 'birthplace_Athens, Greece',
   'birthplace_Atlanta, Ga, US', 'birthplace_Baldwin, Ny, US',
   ...
   'country_ Turkey', 'country_ US', 'country_ Ukraine', 'country_ Wales',
   'bin_0-25', 'bin_25-35', 'bin_35-45', 'bin_45-55', 'bin_55-65',
   'bin_65-75'],
```

Input:

```
 check_cols = [col for col in subset.columns if 'award' in col]
```

Output:

```
['year_of_award', 'award_age', 'award_Best Actor', 'award_Best Actress', 
 'award_Best Director', 'award_Best Supporting Actor', 'award_Best 
 Supporting Actress']
```

If I try referencing any of the above in place of award, I get the same error.

Comment: When you use `pd.get_dummies` it creates multiple columns for each column identified as "category" type, since you are doing one-hot encoding. I am guessing it split your `award` column into multiple columns with different names. Check `subset.columns` after `subset = pd.get_dummies(subset)`.

Comment: @panktijk
I've added the column outputs to the question

Comment: So it does look like your `award` column got split into multiple columns, just like others. You cannot access `birthplace, bin, award, ...` because they all got one-hot encoded. You need to use the new column names now.

Comment: But I can't see the award values in the 2nd index e.g. 'Best Director'

Comment: Are you sure those columns aren't there? Because that seems weird. You haven't pasted your entire columns list, so hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` means the key `award` does not exist in `subset`. You will want to check how subset is structured in order to access it correctly. Right now there is no element `award` in there.

If you provide a little more code on how `subset` is built I may be able to help further.

Comment: I think it's because of this: 
 subset_filtered = subset.query('award== "Best Director"') 
 avrg= subset_filtered["award_age"].mean() #find mean of Best Director ages .

How can I get back to my original subset after this?

Comment: I've identified it happens between the 2nd code snippet and the first. There is no error at the print column line